# Why can't I download Wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, wine

When I try to download `wine` from the software center, there is no install button to click on it only more info, then  a there is a line says that it is available from universe and a `use this source` button, when I click it nothing happens. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed to enable the universe repository and to **reload the software sources**.

Close Software Center, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository universe
 sudo apt-get update
```

After that try it again.